# Unable to change width of TextField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am a newbie to Blackberry, I was just trying out some sample apps in Blackberry. I tried to create a login page. In that, when I tried to change the width of the text field, the text field became invisible.

The below is part of the code to create the TextField.

```java
super(Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
......
t_username = new TextField()
{
    public void layout(int width, int height)
    {
        super.layout(500, 30);
        setExtent(500, 30);
    }
};
t_username.setMaxSize(10);
t_username.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(1,1,1,1),Border.STYLE_SOLID));
```

I tried to create a border to check where it is coming or not, but couldn't find it.
PFB, the snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Nate's answer is correct. I suspect its the hardcoded 500. Edit fields always try to use the full screen width. 500 px width on a smaller screen will obviously run off.

Comment: Thanks Turdnugget for the reply. With Nate's help, I was able to control the width of the TextBox.

Comment: Turdnugget, but I tried with smaller values, also, but no success. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the `TextField#layout()` method

```java
public void layout(int width, int height)
{
    super.layout(500, 30);
    setExtent(500, 30);
}
```

is **one** way that you can set a text field's width.  So, I think there's something else going wrong here.

1) Possibly, when you changed your code, your mistakenly removed the call to

```java
add(t_username);
```

you don't show us where you actually **add** that field, so if you're not calling `add(t_username)` somewhere else, it's not going to be visible.  Fields must be added to a `Manager` or `Screen` to be visible.

2) Perhaps some other code you've written (but not shown) is attempting to do something with a [Graphics](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html) object.  For example, if you're overriding a `paint(Graphics)` method in another field, you may be changing a color (e.g. `graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE)`) and not remembering to reset the original color.  Possibly, your text field is there, but it's the same color as its background.  If this was happening, though, you could still see the text field cursor when you give that field *focus*.   I simply can't tell from your screenshot.

### A Better Way

*Normally* (but not always), it should be the responsibility of the Manager/Screen that contains the field to determine its size.  I think it's poor encapsulation to have most fields set their own width (although there are exceptions to this).  I would recommend using `setMargin()` and the `USE_ALL_WIDTH` flag to set a reasonable width for this text field:

```java
public class TextFieldScreen extends MainScreen {

   private TextField t_username;

   public TextFieldScreen() {
      super(Field.FIELD_VCENTER);

      HorizontalFieldManager row = new HorizontalFieldManager();
      LabelField label = new LabelField("Username");
      label.setMargin(new XYEdges(2, 0, 2, 10));
      row.add(label);

      t_username = new TextField(TextField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
      t_username.setMaxSize(10);
      t_username.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(1,1,1,1), Border.STYLE_SOLID));
      t_username.setMargin(new XYEdges(2, 10, 2, 10));
      row.add(t_username);

      add(row);
   }
}
```

One benefit of this solution, compared to hard-coding a width of `500`, is that if your app supports portrait/landscape rotation, the code above will correctly adjust the field width as the screen width changes.  If you hard-code the field width, the field will be too wide when the device rotates to portrait.

Comment: Hi Nate, Thanks for the quick help. That was very usefull. Thank you. Thank you so much. I was able to control the width.

Also Nate, by overriding getPreferredHeight() and getPrefereedWidth(), can we set the width and height of the TextBox. I tried this option also, but couldn't set both height and width. If we can do, pls provide me a sample code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @JonathonGohan, that's **another** technique for changing field size.  But, that's really a different question.  Can you please post a **new** question here on stack overflow, and explain what you're trying to do?  Thanks.